# K-fold cross-validation for testing model accuracy in MATLAB

Tags: classification, cross-validation, matlab, model

I'm having some trouble truly understanding what's going in MATLAB's built-in functions of cross-validation. My goal is to develop a model for binary classification and test its accuracy by using cross-validation. I'm looking at comparing a few different models, but I'll just use k-nearest neighbor classification for the purposes of this example. I'm providing code for two simplified versions of cross-validation:

```
% INPUTS:
% data = NxM matrix, where N = observations and M = features
% labels = Nx1 matrix with the true labels of each observation

%% Version 1
model = fitcknn(data,labels,'NumNeighbors',kVal); %kVal is some iteratively-determined value

% Calculate misclassification error
cvmodel = crossval(model,'kfold',10);
cvError = kfoldLoss(cvmodel);

% Generate confusion matrix    
predictedLabels = predict(model,data);
R = confusionmat(predictedLabels,labels);


%% Version 2
indices = crossvalind('kfold',labels,10);
confusionMatrix = cell(1,1);
errorMat = zeros(1,10);
for i = 1:10
    test = (indices==i);
    train = ~test;
    knn = fitcknn(data(train,:),labels(train),'NumNeighbors',kVal);
    y = knn.predict(data(test,:));
    index = cellfun(@strcmp,y,labels(test));
    errorMat(i) = sum(index)/length(y);
    confusionMatrix{i} = confusionmat(labels(test),y);
end

% Calculate misclassification error
cvError = 1-mean(errorMat); 

% Generate confusion matrix
R = cat(3,confusionMatrix{:});
R = sum(R,3);
```

Which of these two approaches is the correct implementation? Or are both equivalent? This question can be generalized to other types of classification models in MATLAB, e.g. discriminant analysis. Appreciate any and all input, thanks in advance!

Comment: In your first version, you are predicting the same data your trained your model with. If I am not mistaken, you will always have 100% accuracy

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking whether the `crossval` method's 'kfold' option  is the same as carrying out the k-fold training yourself and combining the results, then it is in principle the same. It is possible that I'm missing something in your code that is a bit different. For instance, I don't know off-hand whether the MATLAB function take the averages of the error rates or weights them by any slight difference in sample sizes across the k folds. But I believe the two approaches are basically the same.

Comment: My primary question was if my coded method is equivalent to what the MATLAB functions 'crossval' and 'kfoldLoss' are doing. In other words, is the methodology behind those two matlab functions the same as what my version of code is doing. I'm also looking at a few other models to test out in MATLAB and I want to be sure the computation of misclassification error from cross-validation is being done correctly.